# curl to follow location along with POST

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm posting a request with POST data using cURL to a PHP script here: http://localhost/example/index.php

How do I hide index.php and just post to http://localhost/example ?

I've tried just posting there, but I get a 301 Moved Permanently header, and if I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to TRUE, the request follows, but seems to lose the POST data - I get nothing at the far end using this file_get_contents('php://input').

Comment: Why exactly is this necessary though?

Comment: What happens if you put a trailing slash, i.e.: localhost/example/  It sounds to me like you might be getting a trailing slash redirect from mod_dir. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: "example" is going to be called by third parties, and I don't want them to see which language I'm using, what file is this, etc.

Comment: mqsoh - YES! Worked. Such a simple mishap. If you would post this as an answer, I will accept it. Also, is there a way to accept both - with trailing slash and without? I don't want the third party to make the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST data is lost upon redirect and you can't avoid that.

What you can do to achieve what you need is to specify in .htaccess (assuming you run Apache)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

And then by requesting `http://localhost/example/` you will recieve index.php in that directory.

The problem appears if you want to give the index.php also for requests going to `http://localhost/example` (without trailing slash), since apache redirects to the url with trailing slash by default, loosing POST data in process. To deal with it, you can fake the request dir:

```
RewriteRule fakedirthatuserknows/?$ /realscriptdir/index.php [L]
```

The `/?` points Apache to use the rule for both cases: with and without trailing slashes.  To avoid redirect, you need to skip the `R=301` flag making it `[L]`. With redirect it would be `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: Thanks for a verbose explanation. Though I still can't manage to write a htaccess rule to accept or rewrite both URL's (with and without trailing slash) to index.php. The problem is that all solutions are done with 301 redirect, which forces curl to lose POST data. When I reach this point, I will change the default name of the script with DirectoryIndex for more cover-up.

Comment: Updated with the example rule.

Comment: I still get a moved permanently header back. What can I still be doing wrong?

Comment: Debug you .htaccess, since it's clearly isn't working. Make sure the rule is placed in aboive dir `localhost/` and not in `example/`, make sure .htaccess is written correctly.

Comment: I had the rule in example/ not in localhost/ - thanks. But now I'm getting a 302 Found response header and the parameters are still not passed.

Comment: Dig in curl_info() and see if you are actually getting index.php response with FOLLOWLOCATION = FALSE. If you do, params can't be lost, since there's no redirect.

Comment: I've just created like-yours example to test what you are saying. Indeed, it returned 302, what was unexpected for me. This is because of the `http://localhost/` at the end of the rule. Replace it with `/` for a total of `RewriteRule example/?$ /example/index.php [L]` and see if it works. Worked for me :)

Comment: Ranty, thanks again for your great insight. Unfortunately, without the http://localhost part I'm getting a 301 header again. What gives?

Comment: 301 is a redirect. Where does it lead?

Comment: If I query the URL http://localhost/example I get a 301 redirect - it leads to http://localhost/example/ (with a trailing slash). Seems that this rule RewriteRule example/?$ /example/index.php [L] does not work as I want it to. It must do something though, because without it, I only get a 302 Found header.

Comment: Seems to me theres another rule to add the trailing slash above the rule we are talking about?

Comment: There were other rules, but I tried commenting them and removing them altogether, and nothing changed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to send requests on the url without trailing slash? :)

Comment: The URL will be on the client/third-party end, so I do not control the URL they put in, and I just don't want the system to not work if they miss the trailing slash.

Comment: After giving it some thought, maybe apache adds the trailing slash by default? Then the solution would be to fake a request dir. `RewriteRule fakedirthatuserknows/?$ /realscriptdir/index.php [L]`

Comment: It worked! Ranty, I cannot thank you enough. You're great. I would like to understand this a little bit more on why this happens. I'm going to accept your answer anyway, but I'd like you to edit it with some of the great info you've provided for me, so that others could gain from your experience.

Comment: Updated the post, removed non-relevant info as well.